# If statement in MySQL not allowing insert

Tags: mysql, if-statement, insert

I'm trying to create an event like this:

```
CREATE EVENT my_schema.event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
  IF DAYOFWEEK(now()) = 7 THEN
  INSERT INTO my_schema.events (`event`, `when`) values ('event', now());
  END IF;
```

But marks an error: Statement is incomplete, expecting ';' at the end of the insert statement, and at END IF also marks error> END is not valid at this position, expecting> EOF, BEGIN...

Comment: Try DO  BEGIN ... IF ... THEN ...; END IF; END

Comment: @MichaelO. Doesn't work, Keeps the error and now END; also marks error

Comment: try redefining delimiter at beginning.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to schedule an event to run on a daily basis, if you only mean it to do something on a particular day of a week? Schedule the event to run that given day of the week instead.